# info.plist file doesn't appear even though the icons are in the Xcode assets folder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I wanted to make an icon for my application. I want to install an application but I'm getting errors like this. I did the solutions in StackOverflow but there was no solution. Although I have edited my `Info.plist` file, I get an error:

```
App Store Connect Operation Error ERROR ITMS-90713: `` Info.plist value is missing. 'CFBundleIconName' is missing a value for Info.plist key 'com.arslantas.erc' in the package. and provide a value for this Info.plist key. For more information see http://help.apple.com/ xcode / mac / current / # / dev10510b1f7. "

App Store Connect Operation Error ERROR ITMS-90022: "Required icon file missing. The package does not contain an exactly '120x120' pixel app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch in .png format for iOS versions> = 10.0. Icon for iOS versions, asset catalog Make sure the Info.plist file contains the appropriate entries referencing the file. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/user_interface"App Store Connect Process Error ERROR ITMS-90023: "Required icon file missing. The package does not contain an app icon in .png format for iOS versions that support iPad Pro, exactly '167x167' pixels for iPad. To support older operating systems, the icon may be required in the package other than an asset catalog. Make sure it contains appropriate entries referencing the file. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/user_interface"App Store Connect Process Error ERROR ITMS-90023: "Required icon file is missing. The package does not contain an exactly '152x152' pixel app icon for iPad in .png format for iOS> = 10.0 versions. To support older operating systems, an icon may be required in a package other than an asset catalog. Make sure that the Info.plist file contains the appropriate entries referencing the file. See. Https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/user_interface "App Store Connect Operation Error ERROR ITMS-90704:" Missing Application Icon. A 1024 x 1024 pixel app icon in PNG format must be added to the Asset Catalog of apps created for iOS, iPadOS, or watchOS. Without this icon, apps cannot be submitted for review.
```

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30CtY.jpg)
 [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgElF.jpg)

Comment: Hey, all problems are written here in this mail from Apple. If you set to support old iOS versions - you have to add images not to Assets. If you have to support iPad - also add images. In any case - all problems listed in mail from Apple.

If you don't support old iOS - set minimum OS version you supported, no need for iPad - set to not universal application but only iPhone.

Comment: Hello Dude I don't need the old iOS. The problem is I understand you but I don't know how to do it. Because I'm just learning and I'm a rookie. I have files on this link. can you solve it and forward it to me?  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jcuJbhmnbWVo63H11Rwr8NZ53nB4Wmzx?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code - it builds successfully, no any issues. If you got it when you upload it to apple servers - here I can't help you, I have strong rules and limits for my accounts about it.

Try to remove "Icon Name" item from plist (it's not needed for now), it can help with first issue. If after it second issue still presented - check carefully all images and all sizes in Assets. Try to recreate it from zero, remove all not used images, don't create duplicates. There is no big magic - just carefully work.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could not upload to Apple servers. I check all images and all dimensions in Assets carefully. It does not give error. How many times I tried to rebuild.

Comment: `<key> CFBundleIconFiles </key>
     <array>
       <string> Icon-60@2x.png </string>
       <string> Icon-76.png </string>
       <string> Icon-76@2x.png </string>
     </array>`
I saw this code somewhere, they used it for the old xcode, should I write to the source code in my info.plist file?

Comment: do you need this content.json file? In the folder I downloaded from the icon creators, the existing icons are in json format. Should I put it in my file?

Comment: no, don't add anything about icons to Info.plist file, use only Assets